# MBA Mid 2011: Black screen on Boot (Installation)

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb, macbook-air

ive been looking around for solutions but neither 'nomodeset'-option nor i915.modeset=0 helped me. I have a Macbook Air Mid 2011 (with Intel Graphics 3000). Im trying to boot it from my USB Stick - which works fine on my Desktop PC (not a Mac) - but when I try booting then, I only get a black screen and after a few seconds the indicator light on my USB stick is completely silent. Nothing else happens. I’m using I’m currently using Ubuntu 15.04 64-Bit.

Comment: Which 15.04 ISO are you trying to boot from? Is your desktop PC also a Mac product? You should always specify the version in your question as a few short months from now, "latest version" will mean something entirely different.

Comment: Sorry. Im currently using Ubuntu 15.04 64-Bit. My Desktop PC is not a Mac.

Comment: Please [edit] new information into your question as comments can be deleted for a number of reasons. I'll do it for you this time...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that your older Macbook Air is supported although it does have an Intel CPU so you might be able to get the 32-bit version to work.

Sources:

Compatibility: http://releases.ubuntu.com/15.04/

Specifications: http://www.anandtech.com/show/4512/the-2011-macbook-air-specs-and-details